# Show function provides json

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

My CouchDB show function will not run the provides('json', ...) function.  It will run the html provides in certain cases though.  Here is the show function:

```
function(doc, req) {
  provides('json', function(){
    return {'json': doc };
  });

  provides('html', function(){
    return "<html><body>html string here</body></html>";
  });

  return {'json': {
    'hello': "goodbye"
    } 
  };

}
```

Here is a sample request when sending text/x-json.  hello:goodbye is also returned if I use Accept: application/json

```
dave@ubuntu-laptop:~/py/liqc$ curl -i -H "Accept: text/x-json" http://127.0.0.1:8001/liqc/user-dave
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 20
Vary: Accept
Server: CouchDB/1.0.2 (Erlang OTP/R14B)
ETag: "6V7EMSS64ZQ5SRLI0EYQVDWES"
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
Date: Mon, 27 Jan 2014 15:54:31 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8, text/x-json

{"hello":"goodbye"}
```

When I request text/html, I also get hello:goodbye.  If I remove the final return of the show function however, application/json will continue to give me hello:goodbye, but text/html will give me the results I want!

```
dave@ubuntu-laptop:~/py/liqc$ curl -i -H "Accept: text/html" http://127.0.0.1:8001/liqc/user-dave
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 42
Vary: Accept
Server: CouchDB/1.0.2 (Erlang OTP/R14B)
ETag: "9B8K3XGK28Y7RL2ART28WLL50"
Date: Mon, 27 Jan 2014 16:02:41 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

<html><body>html string here</body></html>
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this something going on with CouchDB?  I am running a localhost reverse proxy to cloudant BTW.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You're not supposed to use a final `return` if you use `provides`. `return` supersedes any `provides`.

Plus, what do you expect to get when requesting JSON while your show function provides JSON in two different places? Use only `provides` and you will be fine.

About this:

> If I remove the final return of the show function however, application/json will continue to give me hello:goodbye

There is no way you can get `"hello":"goodbye"` if you removed completely the final return. Maybe you forgot to update the design document? Debugging the wrong source code can be very frustrating…

Comment: Thanks for your response!  From all the examples I saw I didn't think I needed a return when using provides, but I was stuck.  Thank you for the confirmation that no return should appear here.  Also, I misspoke about removing the return and still getting hello:goodbye.  What I actually get is a response with content-length 0 if I send accept 'text/x-json' or 'application/json'.

Comment: Knowing that no return is the way to go, I messed with my provides JSON function a little bit.  if I do provides('json', function(){ return {'body':toJSON(doc)}; }); This gives me the correct content-type and it outputs the document!